# SQL: Turn the table's columns into rows and performing basic analysis

Tags: sql

If I have a table with columns A through C (this is just an example) and I have many entries that populates these tables, entries may be Null

ex:

```
A | B | C
1 | 2 | 6
1 | 4 | Null
1 | 0 | Null
```

how can i write a query that woulld output:
- My column names as rows
- a count of number of null entries for each column
- a minimun / maximum / average for each column

i.e:

```
A | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1
B | 0 | 0 | 4 | 2
C | 2 | 6 | 6 | 2
```

where

- 2nd column is the number of NULL entries
- 3rd is the minimum
- 4th is the max
- 5th is an average of all entries for that column

I apprecaite any help you can give me!!

Comment: I'm using a program called Interactive SQL, I think it's sybase database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write three queries, each GROUPed BY a single column, and produce the data needed for the column in the query

be sure to add the columnName as a literal in the SELECT statements

UNION the three queries together and order by columnName

---

EDIT:

another option would be to push columnName and value to a temp table for each column and then the query with the aggregate functions becomes simple...

```
CREATE #tempTable (columnName, columnValue)

INSERT INTO #tempTable
SELECT 'A', A
FROM whatever
```

use a spreadsheet to create your 50 INSERT statements, and then, as I said above, the aggregate query should be simple

Comment: isn't there some sort of automated way to do that? I'd like to do this dor a table that has 50 columns.